# Best practices to implement incremental data load into azure data lake & azure data warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, polybase

I am planning to implement azure BI. I need expert advice on how to implement incremental data load using azure data lake, azure sql datawarehouse, azure data factory + poly base. In which format, we should store data in azure data lake etc.

Thanks 
Nutan Patel

Comment: Sounds like you need a consultant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey @npatel, after almost 2 years, i'm looking for exactly the same answers, can you tell me if you had any success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit broad so will probably get closed on that basis.  There is however an article you should read called: **Azure SQL Data Warehouse loading patterns and strategies**:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2017/05/17/azure-sql-data-warehouse-loading-patterns-and-strategies/